# How to display value from this array in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have been working on a side project and I'm kind of stuck here
So I extract some info in the form of an array using

```
<%= @link.pixels.select{|x| x['platform']=='Facebook'} %>
```

Where the result is

```
[#<Pixel id: 1, platform: "Facebook", name: "Facebook", pixel: "189874014884804", created_at: "2017-10-17 18:44:13", updated_at: "2017-10-17 18:44:13">]
```

How can I extract the value of pixel from this array?
Also, is this the correct approach to select? What if there are two duplicate entries in Pixel with the platform name "Facebook"?

I have been stuck at this for while now.

Comment: I'd consider extracting the pixels in the controller and passing it to the view. You can do something like `@link_pixels = @link.pixels.where(platform: "Facebook")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is display the value of the `pixel` attribute from a collection of `Pixel` instances where the `platform` matches the string `"Facebook"` this is what you'd do:

```
<% @links.pixels.each do |pixel| %>
 <% if pixel.platform == 'Facebook' %>
  Pixel: <%= pixel.pixel %>
 <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: How did I not think of it. I can not thank you enough. I had been stuck on it for hours.

Comment: No worries! I would change the naming also. `pixel.pixel` is redundant